# Highcharts categories xAxis monthly interval

Tags: javascript, highcharts, categories

I'm working in a chart where I have to set the categories in monthly mode, which means first day of every month.

Does anybody know how to do it?

I'm trying to set tickInterval to a month, but it only allows me to have a number less or equal to 25, if it is greater it will not affect the chart

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean to get your x-axis organized like this? http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for, is perfect!

Comment: For dates we recommend to use [datetime](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.type) type of xAxis.